# App42 - Proguard setting necessary (because debug mode works and release mode fails)

Tags: android, app42

I create a query to check, if there exists new data. I compile my app in debug mode, run it and everything works fine. If I compile it in release mode, I get a `NullPointerException`...

Can this be related to proguard? Actually, I didn't find any proguard settings for `App42`...

I use version 3.0.1...

```
Storage storage =  storageService.findDocumentsByQueryWithPaging(db, collection, query, 1, 0);
storage.getRecordCount(); // <= this is NULL!!! But only in RELEASE build
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following proguard setting seems to work:

```
-keep class com.shephertz.** {*;}
```

There may be a better solution, but I could not find any documentation...